# Repair overwritten icons paths

Tags: unity, 13.10, icons

After running [racket-lang](http://racket-lang.org/) install-script all my /usr/share/application/*.desktop files have broken icon paths and corresponding shortcuts are displayed with question marks. Paths are overwritten like this (for standard terminal):

```
Icon=/usr/share/racket/utilities-terminal
```

I'm wondering, if there was a way of broking them at once, maybe there is some easy way to fix them all at once? The problem is I don't know how those paths were looking before. I've tried to replace "/usr/share/racket/" prefix to "/usr/share/app-install/icons/" because I've found this folder has related icons, but this doesn't work until I explicitly specify icon's extension so I can't just write some simple replace script here (icon extensions vary from app to app: in some cases there is "/usr/share/app-install/icons/app.svg", in other "/usr/share/app-install/icons/another-app.png").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change icon path to application name. Try this:

```
for file in /usr/share/applications/*.desktop; do
    grep 'Icon=/usr/share/racket/' "$file" /dev/null
    sed -i 's:^Icon=/usr/share/racket/:Icon=:' "$file"
done
```

Save it as a script ('`script.sh`') and run it as root ('`sudo sh script.sh`').

It will fix all files which need changing.